# Possible values in Salesforce Setup Audit Trail action column

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

Can anyone help us to figure out to identify the possible values of action column of SetupAuditTrail table in salesforce. Do we have any table which stores all action?

ex: `"changedManager", "changedApexPage", "campaignlayout"` etc.

It will be great if some one can point to documentation about all list of action.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm not seeing any obvious documentation for this. What are you trying to build that you're trying to inspect this?

Comment: Thanks @pichittum, I'm part of Cisco Cloudlock team (https://umbrella.cisco.com/products/casb). We are building User behaviour tracking feature to the system. So if we can get all the actions of SF, it will be easy for us to categorise and work accordingly.

Comment: Any new on this?